# FTP: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: ftp

I have a website that I use to upload images to the server and it eventually uploads them to an FTP site from the server.  The problem is that it gets part of the way through the transfer - it transfers some of the files and then stops and gives the error

```
Unable to connect to the remote server
```

This only happens with 1 ftp server.  I have a second ftp server on which this process works fine, so I doubt it's a code issue.  What could the issue be?

thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some FTP servers block flood requests, interrupting the connection. You should try using another FTP client and / or compress all the files, send to server and unzip them from the server using SSH or other method available.

Note: Recommend FileZilla client.